# Why is tensorflow output restricted to (0,1) when using a non linear activation function

Tags: tensorflow

Why does using an activation function cause the outputs of this network to be limited to the range (0,1), when using a linear activation function gives the expected values? Where did the bias value go in my output? Bias is added after the activation function, correct?

```
network = tf.layers.dense(inputs=ins, units=1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

Training:

```
inputs = [[0],[1]]
outputs = [[0],[2]]
for i in range(500):
    print(sess.run(network, feed_dict={inputType: inputs}))
    sess.run(fetches=[train_op, loss], feed_dict={inputType: inputs, outputType: outputs})
```

Example bad output (with sigmoid):

```
[[ 0.17]
 [ 0.98]]
```

Example good output (with no activation function):

```
[[ 1.01]
 [ 1.98]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sigmoid activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is a monotonic function that maps a real value to another in a limited range (typically, (0,1) or (-1,1)).
The activation function in a dense layer is applied **after** the multiplication with the weights and the addition of the bias.

With those premises, your "bad" output is exactly what the network should output when using a sigmoid activation.

Comment: i see. i was always taught the bias was added to the activation function output. how can that be accomplished?

Comment: You'll have to implement the layer logic yourself and invert the order of the operations